# MongoDB mapReduce multikey value counting issue

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

Let me to explain my issue. So I running simple mapReduce query in MongoDB and I am getting really strange results that for me doesn't make any sense. May someone will explain it or find some bug. so...

I am running 2.6.2 version of mongoDB
every document in collection has structure  (I have ~2000 of documents)

```
{
  _id:...,
  data:{
    type:'myType'
  }
}
```

map function

```
var map = function() {
  if(this.data.type== 'myType123') {
    emit(this.data.type, {count:1});
  }
}
```

reduce function

```
var reduce = function(keyCustId, allElems) {
  var res = {};
  res.example = allElems;
  return res;
}
```

I try to run

```
var results = db.myCollection.mapReduce( map, reduce,{ out: "map_reduce_example" });
```

And checking now for results db[results.result].find().pretty(); and it returns me something like that..WHY MONGO MAKES RESULTS SO NESTED?? Is my map or reduce functions are wrong?? If in map->emit(key, value) I pass value not as object but just an integer, all works fine. Please help me figure out this mongoDB nightmare..thank you.

```
{
_id:'myType123',
value:{
  example:[
   {count:1},
   {count:1},
   {count:1},
   {count:1},
   {example: [
     {count:1},
     {count:1}, 
     {example:[
        {count:1},
        {count:1},
        {count:1}
     ]
   ]
   }
  ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the important concept in [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/), which quotes:

> *"MongoDB can invoke the reduce function more than once for the same key. In this case, the previous output from the reduce function for that key will become one of the input values to the next reduce function invocation for that key."*

And later:

> *"... the type of the return object must be identical to the type of the value emitted by the map function .."*

What this means is you **must** return essentially the same data signature from your "reduce" operation as you do from your "map" function. This is because mapReduce does not "reduce" all of the documents for a single key at once. It does it in steps.

So something that has been "partially reduced" can again be called by the reduce function. It will in fact process somewhere around 30 or so items at a time, and since your "reduce" does not emit the same output as what comes from the "map", on it's next trip to the reducer the data is handled differently.

That's why the results you have show up. In order to fix this, the reduce needs to output the same "type" of data as expected in "input":

```js
var reduce = function(key, values) {
  var res = { "count": 0 }
  values.forEach(function(value) {
      res.count += value.count;
  });
  return res;
}
```

Since that is the same data going out as coming in, then your properly "count" your key occurances.